# Infinite while loop with a random number

Tags: c++, random, while-loop

I have this code:

```
void generar() {

    while (true) {
        if (yPos == topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 2;
        } else if (yPos >= topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 1;
        } else if(yPos < topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
        } else {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
        }

        yPos++;

        if(yPos>worldHeight) {
            topOfTheWorld += 0;
            yPos = 0;
            xPos++;
        }

        if (xPos>worldWidth) {
                    break;
        }
    }

std::ofstream output("mapa.txt");
    for(int y=0;y<worldHeight;y++) {
        for(int x=0;x<worldWidth;x++) {
            output<<scene[x][y];

            if(x<(worldWidth-1)){output<<",";}
        }
        if(y<(worldHeight-1)){output<<std::endl;}
    }

MessageBox(0, "World generation has finished!", "Finished!", MB_OK);

}
```

That generates a world based in an array. But when I add:

```
slope = random(5)-2;
```

To:

```
if(yPos == worldHeight) {
    topOfTheWorld += 0; //There would be the slope var...

if(yPos == worldHeight) {
    slope = random(5)-2;
    topOfTheWorld += slope;
```

For some reason the `while` becomes an infinite loop, and I don't know why.

(Random Function)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int random(int n = 0) {

srand(time(NULL));

if(n!=0){
return rand() % n;
} else {
return rand();
}

}
```

(Variables)

```
const int worldWidth = 50;
const int worldHeight = 26;
int topOfTheWorld = worldHeight/2;
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
int scene[worldWidth][worldHeight];
int slope;
```

What can I do?

Comment: Remove the goto: bad programming construct

Comment: For a start do not use `goto`

Comment: do NOT use srand in your random function

Comment: Elaborating on @Bathsheba's comment: just use `break`.

Comment: Where have I to use break? In if (xPos>worldWidth) ??

Comment: @thomas Ruiz is correct here; repeated calls to srand completely ruin the randomn sequence.

Comment: So, what I have to use?

Comment: If you use break, you don't need the finished flag at all. You only exit the loop when you're finished, so being outside of the loop /implies/ that you are finished. Next, what is "topOfTheWorld += 0;" intended for? Consume some CPU cycles?

Comment: no... topOftheWorld will be equal to slope, and slope to random(5)-2

Comment: That explains why you're adding zero to it!

Comment: Yes... Later I will add slope variable..

Comment: I had updated the code! :P

Comment: Call srand function only once - at your "main" function.

Comment: I had to use it only in my int main function??

Comment: Use it once. You can call it in main function - but only once - to keep the "randomness". Also what `topOfTheWorld += 0;` means? :D

Comment: Well `topOfTheWorld += 0` would be `topOfTheWorld += slope`, and slope will make that the terrain go up and down... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show that `scene` is defined as:

```
int scene[worldWidth][worldHeight];
```

However, your code has this:

```
        if (xPos>worldWidth) {
                    break;
        }
```

Which means you will actually write a value outside the array boundary when `xPos == worldWidth`, and this causes undefined behavior. Adding the `slope` variable may cause your variable organization to change in a way that the undefined behavior ends up affecting the values of and or all of your loop control variables.

To fix, you should change the erroneous check with:

```
        if (xPos>=worldWidth) {
                    break;
        }
```

You have since edited your question with code that makes your `yPos` check incorrect in a similar way.

Comment: In short, which I should do? (I'm spanish and I'm not sure if I had fully understood you)

Comment: I had changed `xPos == worldWidth` to `xPos >= worldWidth` it is still infinite.. :/

Comment: Once you have posted the exact code that is producing your error in your question, please don't change it afterwards, because you just invalidate answers. People don't like answering questions that keep changing.

Comment: Ok.. Sorry xD I will put a part of post that say: Codes updated xD

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :D I will never understand logic comparators... xD Is hard for me, idk why... :/

Answer (score 1):

There's a repeated calls to srand in your `random` function

Fixes : -

```
void generar() {

srand(time(NULL)); //Remove srand() from random(), add it here
bool finished = false;

    while (!finished) {
        if (yPos == topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 2;
        } else if (yPos >= topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 1;
        } else if(yPos < topOfTheWorld) {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
        } else {
            scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
        }

        yPos++;

        if(yPos == worldHeight) {
           // slope = random(5)-2; your random call
            topOfTheWorld += 0;
            yPos = 0;
            xPos++;
        }

        if (xPos>worldWidth) {
            finished = true;
           //goto Guardar; not required, 
          //also use of goto is bad programming practice
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, Thanks! But it still infinite! :P

Comment: @Ikillnukes Well, I just pointed out the wrong things, if still its infinte, then probably re-visit your logic, btw what's `worldWidth` ?

Comment: worldHeight is a int...

`const int worldWidth = 50;
const int worldHeight = 26;
int topOfTheWorld = worldHeight/2;
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
int scene[worldWidth][worldHeight];
int slope;`