# Infinite while loop with a std::ofstream C++

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, save, ofstream

Well I have that code that saves an array map on a txt file:

```
std::ofstream output("mapa.txt");
for(int y=0;y<worldHeight;y++) {
    for(int x=0;x<worldWidth;x++) {
        output<<scene[x][y];

        if(x<(worldWidth-1)){output<<",";}
    }
    if(y<(worldHeight-1)){output<<std::endl;}
}
```

I want to integrate it to a while loop:

```
std::ofstream output("mapa.txt");

while (true) {
    if (yPos == topOfTheWorld) {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 2;
    } else if (yPos >= topOfTheWorld) {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 1;
    } else if(yPos < topOfTheWorld) {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
    } else {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
    }

    output<<scene[xPos][yPos] << ",";

    //if(xPos<(worldWidth-1)){output<<",";}

    //if(yPos<(worldHeight-1)){output<<std::endl;}

    yPos++;

    if(yPos>worldHeight) {
        output<<std::endl;
        slope = random(5)-2;
        if(topOfTheWorld<(worldHeight/6)) {
            slope = 1;
        } else if(topOfTheWorld>(worldHeight-10)) {
            slope = -1;
        }
        topOfTheWorld += slope;
        yPos = 0;
        xPos++;
    }

    if (xPos>=worldWidth) {
        break;
    }

}
```

But for some reason the 'while' loop becomes infinite... :/

What can I do?

Comment: `if(xPos>=worldWidth)` breaks the `while` loop, so obviously you need to monitor you `xPos`, re-check your algorithm. Use `std::cout` or a debugger

Comment: Hi P0W! std::cout? I'm using SFML not a console.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good.
However I'm not sure if `scene` is correctly allocated.
You have `yPos>worldHeight` and below `xPos>=worldWidth` which suggests that you're not sure how to compare these. I suspect you got at least one of them wrong. This can easily write outside the scene variable and overwrite yPos or xPos.

Try changing to `ypos>=worldHeight` and see if that works.
If not check how much space you allocate for `scene` and if it looks OK try making it a bit bigger.

Comment: Well http://stackoverflow.com/a/18935216/2466790 Is the solution xD I forget to put >= in the if... As somebody has said me before... So your ans is correct, voted and ticked! :D